# File exists php code

Tags: php

```
<?php

function data_info($data)
{
    if ($data) {
        while (!feof($data)) {
            $buffer = fgets($data);
            if (file_exists($buffer)) {
            $bufferArray[$buffer]['Exists'] = (file_exists($buffer));
            $bufferArray[$buffer]['Readable'] = (is_readable($buffer));
            $bufferArray[$buffer]['Writable'] = (is_writable($buffer));
            $bufferArray[$buffer]['Size'] = (filesize($buffer));
            } else {
                $bufferArray[$buffer]['Exists'] = "No";
            }
        }
        print_r($bufferArray);
    } else {
        echo "The file could not be opened";
    }
}

$data = fopen("D:/xampp/htdocs/Practice/ficheros.txt", "r");
data_info($data);

?>
```

If I have this:
ficheros.txt:
ExistingFile.txt
ExistingFile2.txt
ExistingFile3.txt...
...
It works, but If I have at least 1 NON EXISTING FILE then It will take every file as a non existing one too.

What's wrong? I believe someting in the inner if condition.

---

I mean, what is wrong with the entire code.

I just need to make an array with arrays in it, a good result would be:

```
    array
(
    'text.txt' => array
        (
        'exists' => true,
        'readable' => true,
        'writable' => true,
        'Size' => 64
        ),

    'document.doc' => array
        (
        'exists' => false
        ),

    'photo.jpg' => array
        (
    'exists' => true,
    'readable' => true,
    'writable' => false,
    'size' => 354915
        )
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, well that works in Linux (though I have to trim the filename `$buffer` first).

Comment: Same here. Also, a check for fgets() is needed as feof() usually still returns false after the last successful fgets().

Comment: I know this is old, but I remember that trim fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, It works for me too if I have in ficheros.txt

```
Existingfile.txt
AnotherExistingfile.txt
```

Or

```
FakeFile.txt
FakeFile2.txt
```

But If I combine both of them:

```
Fakefile.txt
Existingfile.txt
```

It won't work, the script in the last case takes both files as non existing ones.

Comment: Hmm.. that seems very strange. Are you using the exact same code as you posted here? Does it matter at what position the non-existing file is in ficheros.txt?

Comment: No, It does not matter at what position ;[

Comment: I agree, very strange. Only things I can think of at this point are something windows-specific or a typo introduced in testing.

Answer (score 0):

Im not 100% **why** your wasn't but I played with it and this is working:

```
<?php

function data_info($data)
{
    if (!$data){return "The file could not be opened";}
    while (!feof($data))
     {
        $buffer = implode('',fgetcsv($data));//fgetcsv will only return an array with 1 item so impload it
        if(file_exists($buffer))
         {
            $bufferArray[$buffer]['Exists'] = (file_exists($buffer));
            $bufferArray[$buffer]['Readable'] = (is_readable($buffer));
            $bufferArray[$buffer]['Writable'] = (is_writable($buffer));
            $bufferArray[$buffer]['Size'] = (filesize($buffer));
         }
        else
         {
            $bufferArray[$buffer]['Exists'] = "No";
         }
     }
    print_r($bufferArray);
}

$data = fopen("c:/file.txt", "r");
data_info($data);

?>
```

The results from the file I used:

```
Array
(
    [c:/messageService.log] => Array
        (
            [Exists] => 1
            [Readable] => 1
            [Writable] => 1
            [Size] => 0
        )

    [c:/setup.log] => Array
        (
            [Exists] => 1
            [Readable] => 1
            [Writable] => 1
            [Size] => 169
        )

    [c:/fake1.txt] => Array
        (
            [Exists] => No
        )

    [c:/fake2.txt] => Array
        (
            [Exists] => No
        )

)
```

On second thought after looking at some of your comments, try it using exact paths instead of just the file name.